# What is T, N, and B in terms of vectors and curvature?

Tags: calculus, vectors, curvature

[image]

Not exactly sure what they want here?

Is T the derivative and N is the normal vector? What's B then? There is no prior reference to these letters in my textbook my teacher's notes/slides, or in previous questions. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T,N$ and $B$ are the unit tangent, unit normal and binormal vectors respectively.

Provided that $r'(t)\neq 0 $ you have $$T(t)=\frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||}$$

$$N(t)=\frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$$ and $$B(t)=T(t) \times N(t).$$

Also see the [Frenet–Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas#:%7E:text=T%20is%20the%20unit%20vector,product%20of%20T%20and%20N.) and [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/TangentNormalVectors.aspx).

Comment: thank you so much! helps a lot

Comment: Hi @Alessio K please can you help with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4396103/585488

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is $T\times N$, the cross product.  There has to be some reference somewhere.  This is standard differential geometry.  $T,N$ and $B$ constitute what's known as a moving frame.  You can look up Frenet-Serret formulas.

Answer (score 1):

These are the Frenet-Serret formulas for curves in $\mathbb R^3$. $B$ is the binormal vector. $T$ is tangent vector and $N$ the normal vector.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas